# Vim Powerline triangles are undersized

Tags: vim, powerline

I've been trying a lot to fix it but always getting this in my terminal

[image: Undersized powerline triangle]

The triangles appearing at the status line are undersized and look a lot awkward.

PS: My font preferences: [image]

**Edit:**  I am using VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 on Gnome Terminal 3.18.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and have installed Vim Powerline plugin.

Comment: `let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'`

Comment: That removes the shapes completely and what I get is up-down and right-left arrows.

Comment: you didn't provide any extra information: vim type? terminal, macvim, gvim, ... . terminal type? os? powerline plugin? vim-airline, light-line, powerline?

Comment: Edited to add the details

Comment: Much Better. Add `set encoding=utf-8` to your `.vimrc`. You may also need to set your `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables to a UTF-8 locale (e.g. `LANG=en_US.utf8`). Also check with some other fonts: [nerd fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#patched-fonts) also have powerline symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vim-airline and faced the ***exactly*** same thing. I thought the solution had to to with font size, or encoding for what it's worth. After a messy trial and error it seems to me the problem is actually with the symbols used. "Better sized" ones together with a suitable font yielded something decent:

[vim-airline + Liberation Mono for Powerline font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg6U1.png)

For vim-airline, an option is to access `:help airline-customization` and copy/paste to my .vimrc the symbols commented as `" old vim-powerline symbols`, for which a dictionary has to be created first: `let g:airline_symbols = {}`.

No idea how it would work for powerline (even though the comment says "vim-powerline-symbols"), but you could try. Worst case scenario you try vim-airline with this tweak.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found larger Powerline triangles in the airline.txt help.  See powerline symbols below. I copy and pasted the correct triangles from the powerline section to get it to work.

Check out the images below for more detail.

```
if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
  let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.crypt = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.maxlinenr = '☰'
let g:airline_symbols.maxlinenr = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.spell = 'Ꞩ'
let g:airline_symbols.notexists = '∄'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" powerline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''
```

[- old airline set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSnbo.png)

[- new airline set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR5HR.png)